# Ejecutar un repo copiado de Github

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, repositorio

He copiado este repo de github: https://github.com/mozilla/http-observatory-website

Si veis las instrucciones descritas, he aplicado todo lo que pone ahí.
Como soy algo nuevo, no sé como ejecutar de manera local este repo. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Answer (score 0):

lo mas seguro tendras que instalar node js para el **node package manager**
.una vez que lo clones con el siguiente comando:
**git clone -b gh-pages https://github.com/mozilla/http-observatory-website.git**
ejecuta el siguiente código para descargar los módulos:
**npm install**
ahora solo tendras que abrir la terminal en la carpeta del proyecto y ejecutar el siguiente comando:
npm run watch
y listo solo tendrás que abrir tu servidor local en el navegador.

Comment: Por qué debo instalar node? En las instrucciones de github solamente indica que se clone el repo. Luego, los dos comandos que ahí se ve, pero más allá de eso, no hay nada.

Comment: Para poder ejecutar esos comandos debes tener instalado el node js, y el npm (El administrador de paquetes de node), es debido al proyecto, este proyecto utiliza node y por eso debes tener instalado el node.js lo puedes instalar aquí https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: El error estaba en -b gh-pages. Con esa copia, se movía a otra rama, lo cual no funciona.